# How to calculate correlation on this plot?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, correlation

How to calculate the correlation between Blue and Red curve. Is the Pearson correlation coefficients works for non-linear data?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, Pearson correlation measures linear relationship, so naturally nonlinear relationships may not be captured by it. However, having a nonlinear looking time series doesn't mean that you can't calculate Pearson correlation. For example, the two series can be exact multiples of each other, however nonlinear they may look when plotted with respect to time.

If you plot the corresponding points of the blue curve and the red curve in to x-y plane, you'll have a much better idea of how they're related, and can calculate the Pearson correlation as well.

In addition, the two series might have been correlated by a lag. In your case, it doesn't seem to be, i.e. lag is $0$, but generally you calculate the cross-correlation function for that.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I did not get the second para "plot the corresponding points of the blue curve and the red curve". Unfortunately this is not time series data. X-axis is kind of spatial from north to south and Y-axis is some feature value and red and blue are results of two instrument. I want to know how much correlation exist in different spatial region (X-axis) between values of two instruments.

Comment: Spatial or temporal, they have the same basic characteristics, i.e. ordered relationship. So, assume it's spatial whenever I say time. For the second paragraph, I meant plot the blue curve's values into x and red curve's values into y axis.

Answer (score 0):

Given the visible relationship between the variables represented by the blue curve (y1) and the red curve (y2), you will find a positive value if you calculate the correlation.

Linear correlation does not appear to be the best measure for the relationship between the variables y1 and y2. It only measures the linear relationship between them.

Something else you may need to think about. 
Let's call x the horizontal-axis variable.There is a threshold value xo on your horizontal axis (just below 0.2), where both y1 and y2 reach their maxima. There seems to be a strong positive relationship between (y1-y2) and the absolute value of (x-xo).

Comment: Thanks, You are true. They show some positive relationship by visual. I want some quantitative measurement. I have lots of such plot where peak and valley of the curve are very complex. And most of the times visual inspection cannot help.